# Utilisation du pronom "lui" dans un livre d'histoire par Lamartine

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, histoire, genre

J'ai une question sur le livre "Histoire des Girondins" par A. de Lamartine. Je tire ce passage du tome 1, livre 1, au début de chapitre XIV. Voici le lien: [Histoire des Girondins](http://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&startRecord=0&maximumRecords=15&page=1&collapsing=disabled&query=dc.relation%20all%20%22cb307254965%22%20sortby%20dc.title%2Fsort.ascending). L'auteur parle de la reine, Marie-Antoinette, la femme de Louis XVI.

> Une femme fut l'ennemie de toute une nation. Sa fierté dedaigna de la détromper. Elle s'enferma dans son ressentiment et dans sa terreur. Emprisonnée dans le palais de Tuileries, elle ne pouvait mettre sa tête à la fenêtre sans provoquer l'outrage et entendre l'insulte. Chaque bruit de la ville **lui** faisait craindre une insurrection.

Pourquoi est-ce que Lamartine dit **lui** dans la phrase dernière? Et pas **elle**? Il est evident pour moi qu'il parle de la reine qui est féminine. Normalement, on fait la différence entre **lui** et **elle** d'après le genre. Est-ce que c'est une typo?

Comment: typo comes from typographie I think. It is a feminine word and a feminine abbreviation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take the sentence:

> Un homme a un bijou. Il le donne à une femme.

You can say:

> Il le donne **à elle**

but you can also say

> il le **lui** donne.

Note that there is no **à** in the second case. In this case, there is no feminine version. So no, it is not a typo, and using **elle** in this case would be wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean you never use the "elle" as pornoun for abbreviation, and always "lui" regardless of gender? And you only make the difference according to gender whenever there is a "à"?

Comment: @user66288 Well, as a subject, there is the difference, when you point out at someone too ("C'est elle!"). But you never use "elle" when it's not the subject and it is **between** the subject and the verb.